# How to convert response getting from an api in JsonPath object to a map or to get the response status code from the response?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am getting a response from an api using this code

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(resp.asString());
```

i want to convert this jsonPath object to a map, or get the response status code before this step and add that code to the map after conversion. With this step i am only getting the response body from the api.
Please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using some external library like jackson for this,

You can use ObjectMapper class, something like this below to convert it to map:

```
public static Map<String, Object> convert(JsonPath jsonPath) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(jsonPath.read(), Map.class);
}
```